# What is the time complexity for this generic bruteforce/backtracking function?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory, backtracking

I am having trouble reasoning what the time complexity of this is. I was writing a backtracking function to solve a problem. To simplify, let's just say I have a list of size "a" and I am allowed to place down 0 or 1 into each element of the list. After trying all combinations, I return. This is clearly 2^(nm).

However, what if during each recursive call I have a constant amount of work to do? I am stuck reasoning through what the complexity is here. Can you point me to sources? From my undergrad studies all I remember is Master's theorem, but this approach is not relevant. (We subtract rather than divide to get the subproblem)

```
def myfunc(x,a):
    if x == a:
       return
    myfunc2() #Some constant time work
    myfunc(x+1,a)
    myfunc(x+1,a)
```

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Well it's definitely at least 2^nm because that's the number of total combinations. I'm wondering what this constant work adds

Comment: My crayons are all off and broken  at this moment. Sorry I coldnät be more helpful.

Comment: @JobHunter69: Constant multipliers to the work don't change big-O. It's why big-O isn't always the most important thing in real world algorithms; if your choices are a `O(n)` algorithm with a constant multiplier of 10,000 or a `O(n²)` algorithm with a constant multiplier of 1, and your inputs are almost always `n < 10,000`, you probably want to use the "inferior" `O(n²)` algorithm (possibly including both and dynamically selecting between them based on input size).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes I know all of that, but that's not relevant here

Comment: @JobHunter69: You clearly don't if you think "what this constant work adds" would affect the big-O in any way. It's quite clear that calls to `myfunc` are proportionate to calls to `myfunc2`, making any constant time work from `myfunc2` a constant multiplier to the total work (and therefore wholly irrelevant to big-O).

Comment: @ShadowRanger If you have 2^m unique patterns of bits in a 0-1 vector and for each element you do 4 operations of work, that would be 2^m*4*m operations, which is what I was confused about but realized I was overcounting. What you said everybody already knows. The answerer below gives a good proof. Your argument doesn't make any sense. What if you had (x)^n and now you do (c*x)^n. That's not just a constant anymore. It's not obvious that everything is linear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the time complexity is `T(n) = m + 2T(n - 1)`. Although we can't apply Master's theorem here, we can use substitution:

```
T(n) = m + 2T(n - 1)
     = m + 2(m + 2T(n - 2))
     = m + 2m + 4(m + 2T(n - 3))
     = ∑(i = 1, i = n) m2^i
```

Evaluating this, we have `m2^n` or ϴ(2^n).

Recursion doesn't really offer you any benefits here over readability. You could see savings if you combined this with memory of what you've evaluated, however. In that case, evaluating the time complexity becomes more... complex.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is obviously exponential.

And the `myfunc2()` contribution is negligible unless `x`  is less than 2.

Maybe if myfunc2() is searching for 42.